# Explaining the need for MySQL and Puma servers

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database

Very simple question from an absolute beginner but I can't find an answer anywhere, maybe it's just too simple. So sorry in advance:

If I create a rails app using Mysql. Do I have to effectively run 2 servers? i.e. the mysql server and the rails server `rails s` and `mysql.server start` As this is the only way I can see my app in `localhost:3000

If I stop one or the other I lose the connection.
It sounds dumb as I write it but I can take a flaming just to get an answer, I've been looking for hours. Thanks

Comment: Rails and MySQL are just software which needs to be running in order to use them. Both of them need to be running if you want to use MySQL and rails. Just like a desktop/ laptop can run multiple things at once, they can both run on the same physical machine (if by "server" you mean the physical machine).

Comment: I suppose my point is that for me to see my app in localhost:3000 I seem to need a mysql server running and also to run rails server, which seems to be handled by Puma according to terminal as it boots. Is this correct? Or have I set it up wrong? thx

Comment: There's nothing wrong with being new to programming or some particular way of programming. There's no need to brand yourself a "NOOB".

Comment: Sounds like your rails app contains MySQL statements (does something with a MySQL database) - if that's the case then having both rails and MySQL running is exactly how it should be :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "server" can mean many things depending on context, but in this particular case you mean "server process" or "server daemon" more specifically.

MySQL runs as a background process. `rails server` runs as a foreground process. Both of them are termed "server processes" because you can interact with them from other processes and they "serve" results. This comes from the "client/server" model of computing. A server process might actually be the client of another server process, things tend to chain together.

Both are necessary to run your application. Normally your MySQL server auto-starts when you boot your machine. If it doesn't that's something to fix, it's a big hassle otherwise. The `rails s` method for running sites is kind of primitive but a good place to start. Using [Passenger](https://www.phusionpassenger.com) or [Pow](http://pow.cx), if that's an option, is often a lot better.

Comment: Awesome that's the kind of assurance I was looking for, thanks for taking the time to reply. Trust me I'm all about primitive at this stage. So the rails server is Puma in my case, is that right? And it handles the local files etc for pulling the app together, Mysql is doing what then? Apart from waiting to handle the db I assume theres something else going on otherwise it wouldn't stop me from seeing the app in browser.

Comment: @MysticChimp Sort of, but not really. First a web request comes in - Puma deals with that, then passes it over to rails. Your rails app then has one or more MySQL queries in it; whenever your app runs those, it makes the request to MySQL. This collection of programs is broadly called a _"web stack"_ because of how one is kind of on top of another.

Comment: Ok I see, makes sense now. Had I created the app with SQLite3 there would have been no need to run Mysql concurrently and rails server would do the job on its own I presume.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys thats literally been bugging me for hours.

Comment: @MysticChimp Yep that's right - SQLite is an _embedded_ database, meaning it's part of your rails app - built in, if you like. Whereas MySQL is more like a giant database factory which you have to send requests to so it can deal with them in a much bulkier way (see e.g. [how to decide between them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813890/sqlite-or-mysql-how-to-decide) for more detail there).